# How to just update the value in the table upon the click on the submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I've been reading on lots of others question already but I can't find the solution to it. My employer ask me to remove the selection part on my drop down when a patient is discharged.

So, he asked me to remove the drop down selection button of the discharge part, and asked that the table will be updated only by the use of submit button. What should I do then? Can you guys give me some guide?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Below is my code.

```html
<form action="add_status_submit.php" method="POST" class='form-horizontal form-validate' id="bb">
 <div class="control-group">
  <label for="textfield" class="control-label">Patient : </label>
  <div class="controls">
   <select name="pid" id="select2" class='chosen-select form-control' data-rule-required="true">
    <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
    <?php
    $query = "select * FROM ipd_p  ORDER BY id DESC";

    //echo $query;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)!=0){
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
      echo "<option value='" . $row['pid']."'>" .  $row['name'] . "</option>";
     }
    }
    ?>      
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="control-group">
  <label for="textfield" class="control-label">Discharged : </label>
  <div class="controls">
   <select name="dis" id="select" class='chosen-select form-control' data-rule-required="true">
    <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
    <option value="Available">Yes</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class='control-group 11'><label for='textfield' class='control-label'>Status :</label>
  <div class='controls'><input type='text' name='details' class='input-large' data-rule-minlength=1 placeholder='Status' required></div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-actions">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Which selection from form must be removed after discharged?